# Filtering based on search with Pagination i.e. on entire set of records

Tags: angularjs, pagination

I am able to search only the current page records, However I need to search the entire set of records returned from server. This is my code:

```
<tr ng-repeat="brt in $parent.visibleBrtList = (currBrtList 
            | orderBy: state.orderBy : state.reverseOrderByDirection 
            | filter: pageFilter(state.page, state.itemsPerPage)
            | filter: searchKeyword) ">
```

I have also tried to modify it like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="brt in currBrtList
            | filter: pageFilter(state.page, state.itemsPerPage)
            | filter: searchKeyword">
```

currBrtList has 200 records, itemsPerPage is 10.

Here is pageFilter function:

```
 $scope.pageFilter = function() {
    var from = $scope.state.page * $scope.state.itemsPerPage;
    var to = from + $scope.state.itemsPerPage;
    return function(item, index) {
        return index >= from && index < to;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `limitTo` filter for pagination:

```
<tr ng-repeat="brt in currBrtList
            | orderBy: state.orderBy : state.reverseOrderByDirection
            | filter: searchKeyword
            ̶|̶ ̶f̶i̶l̶t̶e̶r̶:̶ ̶p̶a̶g̶e̶F̶i̶l̶t̶e̶r̶(̶s̶t̶a̶t̶e̶.̶p̶a̶g̶e̶,̶ ̶s̶t̶a̶t̶e̶.̶i̶t̶e̶m̶s̶P̶e̶r̶P̶a̶g̶e̶)̶
            | limitTo: state.itemsPerPage : state.page*state.itemsPerPage" >
```

The first argument is the `limit`; the second, the `begin`.

Also be sure to filter *before* pagination.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS `limitTo` Filter API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo)

Comment: Hi thanks for this, I'll try to implement. However can you please explain what do you mean by filter before pagination?? I think that's the important part. Sorry, I'm quite new to angular

Comment: If the code filters the list after the `limitTo` pagination, you will get pages with no data because the data has been filtered out,

Comment: Thanks it worked.. didn't realise the order of filter matters so much :)